# Limit of size sourcedata in ADF

Tags: xml, azure-data-factory

We have a COPY DATA activity that uses an REST-API as a SOURCE.
This Source returns an XML file.
Whenever the XML file returned is larger then 300 MB the copy activity fails.
However, I can nowhere find any documentation regarding this limit.
Is this a true limit or is the developer misunderstanding what is happening?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: internal error (ponting toards the azure function thar creates the blob)